Can I travel with Diazepam and Phenobarbital to Turkey?
my son needs these meds to control seizures, just wondering if these drugs are legal to bring in Turkey? We have drs note and stickers+prescription on original packaging. Is there a possibility that these can cause issue? My son has to take phenobarbital everyday and diazepam is rescue medicine.
Thanks in advance

What have you researched so far to try to find the answer? Have you contacted a Turkish embassy/comsulate in your country for advice, for example?

Yes I did, no help so far. They kept sending me to voice mail or told me we dont have any information regarding that matter. So dont really kniw!

Try to check on the web (on official sites). And also you should get the "real name" (every country may use different names), so if you know the chemical name is better (also when you pass immigration). -- In general: if you find information on official site (custom): good, else: you may expect also custom officers will not know much more, so in small quantities it may be ok (large quantities: they will ask the specialist).

After a bit of searching, I found this guidance from here. IDK if it’s up to date but it contains email/telecon contact details that might be useful.

@Traveller the email is an email of an employee, not a general email, I'd place a high likelihood on it not working.
